# Преобразование массива в DataTable

Tags: c#, массивы, datatable

Имеется массив следующего типа:

```
public class UserInfo
{
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }

    public string FIO { get; set; }
}
```

Как мне добавить данные UserId из этого массива в DataTable? Пробовал таким образом но не получается:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        Workers = new ObservableCollection<UserInfo>();
    }

    public ICollection<UserInfo> Workers { get; set; }

    protected override async Task InitializeAsync()
    {
        var workers = await _procedures.GetUsers();
        Workers.ReplaceRange(workers);
    }

    var idWorkers = new DataTable();

    foreach (var worker in Workers)
    {
        idWorkers.Rows.Add(worker.UserId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Зачем вы вообще используете этот `DataTable`?

Comment: @АндрейNOP нужно в хранимую процедуру передать переменную со всеми id пользователей, которая будет добавлена к существующей таблице

Comment: Вы добавляете в DataTable строки, но там нет ни одного столбца же. Или вы не показали его/их добавление.

Comment: @АндрейNOP так, добавил столбец. Так должно добавляться или нет? Просто теперь пытаюсь просмотреть данные которые должны быть в datatable, однако мне выводит System.Data.DataRow столько же раз, сколько было пользователей

Comment: А как выводите?

Comment: @АндрейNOP MessageBox.Show(idWorkers.Rows.ToString());

Comment: Ну так, конечно, не будет работать, там внутри строки надо смотреть конкретную ячейку и значение в ней, наверное.

Comment: Посмотрите, например, что лежит в `idWorkers.Rows[0][0]` - здесь первый 0 это индекс строки, второй 0 - индекс столбца внутри этой строки.

Comment: @АндрейNOP ага, все есть, спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        Workers = new ObservableCollection<UserInfo>();
    }

    public ICollection<UserInfo> Workers { get; set; }

    protected override async Task InitializeAsync()
    {
        var workers = await _procedures.GetUsers();
        Workers.ReplaceRange(workers);
    }

    var idWorkers = new DataTable();
    var column = new DataColumn { DataType = typeof(Guid) };
    idWorkers.Columns.Add(column);

    foreach (var worker in Workers)
    {
        idWorkers.Rows.Add(worker.UserId);
    }
}
```